# Is possible to change the ID of an attribute?

Tags: magento2.3, database, product-attribute

I have these attributes:

- id 199 = size
- id 200 = color
- id 210 = number
- id 220 = measure

Those are used to create configurable items in the product view.

Color is showing above number and measure, while the size is showing the bottom.

[image: number]
[image: size]

I need that color attribute is always displayed on top and I guess it's related to the attribute ID. Is possible to change the id 199 = size with another ID > 200 (color's id) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution.

Just run those two sql queries:

update catalog_product_super_attribute set position = 0 where attribute_id = 200;

update catalog_product_super_attribute set position = 1 where attribute_id != 200;

Those will set position = 0 for color attribute in all products and position = 1 for rest of the attributes. This way color will be always first.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is the wrong one.

Obviously you can always change the id in raw from your database and it's probably what magento use to sort by default but the real way of doing it would be :

Extending the filter rendering; there might use a collection or an array or whatever that they print. Before sending that array to the template you need to order it as you wish.

Altering raw ids in database is for me a terrible idea. Because when your feature will be sent to an other env like production...then you will still have the firsts ids and you will have to make all the changes again.

But then you will have a new request...hey i want a filter "age" between color and number...so you will change again raw ids ? Obviously not.

So the way is to sort the filter collection used by magento so as this logic of changing the order will appear int he code and won't be magical from the database..

Answer (score 0):

Edit attribute > Storefront properties > Position to reorder on frontend:
[image]

Comment: Already tested, not working for configurations. I have position "2" for color and position "7+" for others attributes, but "size" still appears above "color".